# How to append the list in Python for certain index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list like this;

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] # list of 9 elements
```

I want to have another `list2` like this..

```
list2 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1] # list of 10 elements
```

`list2` is formed by keeping `0th` element & the `8th` element from `list1` & adding adjacent elements next to each other in `list1`.
This is what I did;

```
list2 = [None] * 10
list2[0] = list2[9] = 1

for idx, i in enumerate(list1):
    try:
        add = list1[idx] + list1[idx+1]
        #print(add) 
        list2[1:9].append(add)
    except:
        pass

print(list2)
```

But I am not getting the desired output... actually the list2 is not updating, I am getting:

```
[1, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 1]
```

Comment: `list2[1:9].append(add)` creates *a new list*, then appends to it, then that new list is immediately discarded.

Comment: are you doing this a lot and is performance important?

Comment: yes @ Tim Richardson .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternate way to achieve your desired result is to effectively shift `list1` by prepending a list with one entry of 0 to it, and then add it to itself (extended by an entry of 0 to match lengths), by using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to create a list of tuples that can be iterated over:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

list2 = [x + y for x, y in zip([0] + list1, list1 + [0])]
print(list2)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the other answers but I would do it in two lines of code using an intermediate list (or just modify the original list if you won't need it anymore) to make the padding easier to see:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

lyst = [0, *list1, 0]
list2 = [prev + cur for prev, cur in zip(lyst, lyst[1:])]

print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
list2 = list1[:1] + [x + y for x, y in zip(list1[0:], list1[1:])] + list1[-1:]
```

Comment: if OP is newer to Python, which they might be, this might be less than _readable_ for them

Comment: @aws_apprentice perhaps, but given that the accepted and most upvoted answer is basically the same as this one, I'd say it's OK.